# SQL database date format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.
In tabledefinition the default format for date is mm:dd:yyyy , is there any way of changing the format to dd:mm:yyyy from sql settings or something like that.

I have globalization in form load(for dd/mm/.yyyy) but when I'm selecting from datasource some values between some dates :

```
 string d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(date1.Text).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
 string d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date2.Text).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
 SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM test WHERE Name = '"+name.Text+"' AND Date between '"+d1+"' AND '"+d2+"'";
```

It works only for `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Is there any way to change it?

Comment: What is the datatype of column Date in SQL Server ? is it DateTime ?

Comment: A good habit is to use ISO date format in your SQL queries, i.e. YYYYMMDD

Comment: type Date , and default format : mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Is this an invitation of [SQL-Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)? Use parameters.

Comment: [*Use Parameters*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and, having converted the text into dates, *keep* them as dates. Let ADO.Net translate .NET dates into SQL dates, and avoid dealing with formatting *at all*

Comment: @TimSchmelter is absolutly right. USE PARAMETERS!

Comment: @Jax mm//dd/yyyy is NOT a default format, it is the US-ONLY format and therefore fails in any other collation. The ISO format works for all collations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its better if you can use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz.aspx) with the query. Also if your column type is Date, then its better if you don't convert them to string for the comparison. Try the following

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@d1", date1);
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@d2", date2);
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM test WHERE Name = '"+name.Text+"' AND Date between @d1 AND @d2";
```

Also use parameters for Name

Answer (score 4):

Avoid the unnecessary conversions back to string and use parameters:

```
DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(date1.Text);
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date2.Text);
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM test WHERE Name = @name AND Date between @d1 AND @d2";
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddParameterWithValue("@name", name.Text);
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddParameterWithValue("@d1", d1);
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddParameterWithValue("@d2", d2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a parametrized query, and all your problems will disappear. :)

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM test WHERE Name = @p_Name AND Date between @p_from AND @p_to";
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add ("@p_Name", SqlDbType.String).Value = name.Text;
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add ("@p_from", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = d1;
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add ("@p_to", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = d2;
```

Comment: It is what it is; you define a query which has parameters.  These act as 'placeholders'.  You define what the parameters are, what datatype they should contain, and assign a value to it.  After that, all will be taken care of for you (data-formats, quoting, etc... )

Answer (score 1):

Try to use parameters:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE Name = @Name AND Date between @DateLow AND @DateHigh";
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("Name", name.Text);
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("DateLow", DbType.DateTime, d1);
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("DateHigh", DbType.DateTime, d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand= " SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE Name =   
'"+name.Text+"' AND Date BETWEEN  
CONVERT(Date,'"+d1+"' , 105)  AND CONVERT(Date,'"+d2+"', 105)"
```

try this....